# Xamarin,Android How to navigate between two axml pages

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an axml page called Main.axml and a MainActivity.cs  file ,i collect values from textbox in axml page and update it in database using web services  after updating the database i want to move to a an axml page which just displays the text "Thank you for entering the data".Can anyone please tell how to navigate to another axml page from MainActivity.cs

i tried this in windows mobile app ,but it is not working for Xamarin android :

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Thanks.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: Good tutorial can be found here:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/hello,android_multiscreen_quickstart/

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Artur Shamsutdinov for the link to the article.For anyone who wants to skip reading the article .Please find below the code we have to use in our Activity Page,

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ThankyouActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);
```

in ThankYouActivity.cs we can use this code to show the axml page,which will then show thankyou.axml on screen

```
 SetContentView(Resource.Layout.thankyou);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following short way:

```
StartActivity(typeof(ThankyouActivity));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it:

```
Button thankYou = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnThankYou);
thankYou.Click += delegate { StartActivity(typeof(ThankYouActivity)); };
```